# Threads giving up CPU control - Seeming contradiction in textbook

Tags: multithreading, process, operating-system, multiprogramming

I'm learning about threads and processes in an Operating Systems course, and I've come across an apparent contradiction in my textbook (Modern Operating Systems, 4th Ed. by Tanenbaum and Bos).  I'm sure there's a something I'm misinterpreting here, it'd be great if someone could clear things up.

On page 106:

> Another common thread call is thread_yield, which allows a thread to voluntarily give up the CPU to let another thread run.  Such a call is important because there is no clock interrupt to actually enforce multiprogramming as there is with processes

Ok fine - so how I interpret that is that threads will never give up control unless they willingly cede it.  Makes sense.

Then on page 116, in an example of threads mishandling shared information:

> As an example, consider the *errno* variable maintained by UNIX.  When a process (or a thread) makes a system call that fails, the error code is put into *errno*.  In Fig. 2-19, thread 1 executes the system call **access** to find out if it has permission to access a certain file.  The operating system returns the answer in the global variable *errno*.  After control has returned to thread 1, but before it has a chance to read *errno*, the scheduler decides that thread 1 has had enough CPU time for the moment and decides to switch to thread 2.

But didn't thread 1 just get pulled from the CPU involuntarily?  I thought there was no way to enforce thread switching as there is with process switching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This makes sense if we're going about process-level threads instead of OS-level threads. The CPU can interrupt a *process* (regardless of what thread is running), but because the OS is not aware of process-level threads, it cannot interrupt them. If one thread inside the process wants to allow another thread to run, it has to specifically yield to the other thread.

**However**, most languages these days use OS-level threads, which the OS does know about and can pre-empt.

Comment: So in other words, if the threads are implemented at the Kernel level, the OS can absolutely interrupt them and switch to another one (Possibly at an inopportune time)?

If that's the case, it seems to sort of defeat the purpose of multi-threading - isn't one of the main reasons for multi-threading to have multiple threads working cooperatively?

Comment: Correct, the OS can absolutely interrupt OS-level threads when they're in usermode. Threads work cooperatively using synchronization points, typically by calling into the kernel (which cannot be pre-empted) to communicate (via a semaphore or lock or compare-and-set). You should also read up on *critical sections*.

Comment: @Tulkas_44 no it is not.  The 'main reason' is to have CPU execution on  cores managed in the same way as other computer resources - only supply it to threads that need it and deny it to threads that cannot.  'Possibly at an inopportune time', yes, but PROBABLY at an opportune time - when another thread that was waiting on I/O or inter-thread signaling becomes ready.  Without preemptive multitasking, your computer would be dog-slow at many tasks, and others, like video playback/streaming, would just not happen.

Comment: So essentially, the scheduling algorithm is preemptive in that it lets a process run for a maximum amount of time (enforced by periodic clock interrupts), and in the case of the example in my question, the threads are just processes from the point of view of the kernel, so the clock interrupts were forcing thread switching.  

Please correct me if I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: @Tulkas_44 essentially. Modern processes are just a group of threads that share memory space. The clock interrupts force thread switching so that no one thread starves the system; most threads are often blocked by some external resource, and are descheduled until that resource becomes available.

Answer (score 0):

The confusion is that there are two different ways threads are implemented. In ye olde days there was no thread support at all. The DoD's mandate of the Ada programming language (in which tasks—aka threads—were is an integral part) forced the adoption of threads.

Run time libraries were created (largely to support Ada). That worked within a process. The process maintained a timer that would interrupt a threads and the library would switch among threads much like the operating system switches processes.

Note that this system only allows one thread of a process at a time to execute, even on a multiprocessor system.

Your first example is describing such a library but it is describing a very primitive thread library where thread scheduling is based upon cooperation among the various threads of the process.

Later, operating system started to develop support for threads. Rather than scheduling a process, the operating system schedules threads for execution. A process is then an address space with a collection of threads. Your second example is talking about this kind of thread.